# How to use selenium to automate android applications without a server

Tags: selenium, appium

I have used selenium and appium to automate my Whatsapp, but whenever I have to do that, I need to use my PC. Is there any way to automate android applications without a server or computer/laptop ?

Comment: Is there a reason why you can't install the android sdk on your pc?

Comment: I have done that but I want to automate my WhatsApp without any external hardware like laptop/computer

Answer (score 0):

No, you're depending on Appium to make the connection between your code and any mobile-tablet application.

Comment: How can I do that without appium ?

Comment: So, Appium is making the connection between your code and the device, right? Of course, you're using another tool to spy on application's elements. None of these tools are available for mobile/tablet, only for windows, so you're kinda blocked. If you can find a record&play tool like Selenium IDE for mobile, maybe will work, or maybe you can create your own mobile app to do this.